# Selenium: How to scroll in inner div using selenium in python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Want to scroll the chats in web.whatsapp.com. Have shared the pseudo-code below:

```
recentList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_2wP_Y']")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 500);")
```

Looking forward for a solution so as to scoll in web.whatsapp.com till the last chat.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try below code

```
recentList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_2wP_Y']") 

for list in recentList :
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", list )
    // other operation
```

Comment: do you have solution to scroll till the last chat?

Comment: The last chat is the last element in the `recentList` collection. There's no need to scroll through each of the elements in the collection in a loop, only the last.

Comment: Try changing `list` to `list[:-1]` for the last chat.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
eula = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_2wP_Y']") 

for my_xpath in eula:
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', my_xpath)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Please expand on this answer to provide some more context

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple approach which worked for me when none of the other answers did.

First make sure you are selecting the div with the "scrollbar" element.

```
scrolling_element= find_element_by_xpath(scrolling_element_xpath)    
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', scrolling_element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with Python only (using h`TouchActions` class' `scroll_from_element` [method](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions.html#selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions.TouchActions.scroll_from_element)):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions import TouchActions

recent_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_2wP_Y']")
touch_action = TouchActions(driver)
touch_action.scroll_from_element(recent_list[1], 0, 150).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

`element` should be a scrollable element

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scroll(0,arguments[0].scrollHeight);", element)
```