# Unable to collect titles from a webpage in the right way

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to get some titles out of some images from a webpage. The thing is the content I would like to parse are located near the bottom of that page. So, If i try like the conventional way to grab that, the browse fails.

So, I used a javascript code within my scraper to let the browser scroll to the bottom and it worked.

However, I don't think it's a good solution to keep up so tried with `.scrollIntoView()` but that didn't work either. What can be the ideal way to serve the purpose?

This is my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

URL = "https://www.99acres.com/supertech-cape-town-sector-74-noida-npxid-r922?sid=UiB8IFFTIHwgUyB8IzMxIyAgfCAxIHwgNyM0MyMgfCA4MjEyIHwjNSMgIHwg"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") #I don't wish to keep this line
time.sleep(3)

for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#carousel img"):
    print(item.get_attribute("title"))
driver.quit()
```

Comment: You can look into this ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027558/selenium-how-to-scroll-in-inner-div-using-selenium-in-python/48027604#48027604

Comment: Can you be explicit about what you are looking for by _the content I would like to parse are located near the bottom of that page_

Comment: There are five pictures under the category of `Banks Approved` in that page. I would like to grab the titles imprinted on those pictures @DebanjanB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below code that should allow you to scroll to required node and scrape images:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

banks = driver.find_element_by_id("xidBankSection")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", banks)
images = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#carousel img"))) 

for image in images:
    print(image.get_attribute("title"))
```

Some explanation: initially those images are absent in source code and generated inside BankSection once you scrolled to it, so you need to scroll down to BankSection and wait until images generated

Comment: @sir Andersson, Your code works If I manually stir the mouse while scraping process is going on, otherwise the browser stays at the bottom and the script throws an error `timeout exception`. +1 for this. How to fix the rest I meant, manual intervention.

Comment: @novice-coder, Do you mean that my code doesn't allow to scroll down to BankSection or even after scroll executed those images still not available and you have to make another little scroll? P.S. sorry, I have no possibility now to check how it actually works(

Comment: Nope sir, not that. Your script does scroll to the bottom and throws timeout exception. I don't need to scroll up or down while your script is running. However, Just a little movement (nowhere specific) of my mouse (while your scraper is running) can parse those items. I barely noticed your solution fails in many different cases.

Comment: @novice-coder, now I have possibility to check how my code works, but can't open target page - got status 412 Precondition Failed...

Comment: I'm not having any problem to open that site @sir Andersson.

Comment: Hmm.. This is weird: 6 hours ago I was able to open it, but no I got [this](https://imgur.com/bIiKCP6)

Comment: Okay. I'm gonna accept this as an answer. However, I may get back in near future and request you to take a look, if that time you can access the webpage.

Comment: It's not necessary - you should accept answer only if it solved your problem.

Comment: Also try to import `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys` and add `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.DOWN)` just after `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", banks)` - it should allow you to perform  just a little additional scroll down

Comment: It is done. Only this line suffices: `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)`. No scroll into view is required. Thanks sir for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below line of code

```
recentList = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#carousel img"):

for list in recentList :
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", list )
     print(list.get_attribute("title"))
```